# How to implement an OAuth resource server to validate access tokens from different authorization servers?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

If I want to implement a resource server which can take multiple generic authorization servers, how can I make sure my resource server can validate the these access tokens from different servers?

```
+------+              +----------+
| Auth |              | Resource |
+------+              +----------+
         \            /
           +--------+
           | Client |
           +--------+
```

Despite the limited drawing above, say the client goes through the usual `authorization code flow` to eventually obtain an access token from the auth server and then send it to the resource server to fetch resource which belongs to a particular user which authorizes the client to fetch resource on behalf of the user.

It is not just OAuth authorization server I'm intending to support. I'm actually assuming it's an generic OpenID connect Identity server (IdP). So Auth could be Google's openID, or Microsoft's Identity Provider, or some third party generic OpenID IdP which I may not have control over its implementation.

I'm also not in control of the client, which is some third party server application which want to consume the API from the resource server.

I am trying to implement the resource server. The question is, how do I know which OAuth authorization server (or OpenID connect IdP) provided the access token that I'm suppose to validate? Does OAuth protocol say anything about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the Resource server (The API that you tries to protect) has a fixed dependency on one IdP, it would be very confusing if an API accepted tokens from multiple providers. You typically have one IdP inside your organization that issues tokens that your services trust.

For in ASP.NET core, the API downloads the public keys from this service and uses it to validate the signature of the incoming access token.

Then inside the token there is also typically an audience claim that indicates to whom the access token was intended for and the API can verify that as well.

You can connect so that you through your IdP you can authenticate users using external identity providers, like this picture shows:

[image]

Comment: Is it that typically the same organization provides both the IdP and the resource server? The scenario I'm describing where auth, client, resource are from three different organizations is not what Oauth is catering to?

Comment: There's many ways to do it, but typically you would only trust your own issued tokens in your organization, but then an other organization may ask your IdP for a token based on some other credentials to use against your APIs. It would be confusing if the token your receive have different claim in them (different IdPs sometimes provides slightly different claim in them).

Comment: I was thinking about having third party accessing my protected resource, but allow third party to use its own existing user credential, or external ones like Google openid. That way the user doesn't have to yet register for another IdP.

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: A great tip. It also raises many more questions to how it is done. I guess the flow describe on the page [here](https://www.authlete.com/developers/tutorial/idp/) answered a lot of the questions I have about the mechanisms of the central/intermediate IdP you described. So the central/intermediate IdP is acting as an oauth client (openid relay party) when talking to an external IdP. And a separate access token can be generated by the central IdP. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, your IdP becomes a trusted client of some external IdP, like Google/GitHub/FB... It is pretty straight-forward to implement and most IdP has tutorials about this "Federated Identity"